# add a template file to custom theme

Tags: 7, theming

I've added a new theme to my site and I've added a new content type called code_excerpt. Now, I've created a new template called `code_excerpt.tpl.php` and added it to my theme folder but when I created a new page using the newly created code_excerpt as content type it appears that the template used is still `page.tpl.php` as opposed to `code_excerpt.tpl.php`. As I'm pretty new to drupal, is there anything else that I need to do in order to get my content type to utilize that template? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it needs to be `node--code-excerpt.tpl.php`

don't forget to clear the cache.

Copy `node.tpl.php` to `node--code-excerpt.tpl.php` then modify code as necessary.

Here is my node.tpl.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a node.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $title: the (sanitized) title of the node.
 * - $content: An array of node items. Use render($content) to print them all, or
 *   print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use
 *   hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a
 *   given element.
 * - $user_picture: The node author's picture from user-picture.tpl.php.
 * - $date: Formatted creation date. Preprocess functions can reformat it by
 *   calling format_date() with the desired parameters on the $created variable.
 * - $name: Themed username of node author output from theme_username().
 * - $node_url: Direct url of the current node.
 * - $terms: the themed list of taxonomy term links output from theme_links().
 * - $display_submitted: whether submission information should be displayed.
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
 *   preprocess functions. The default values can be one or more of the following:
 *   - node: The current template type, i.e., "theming hook".
 *   - node-[type]: The current node type. For example, if the node is a
 *     "Blog entry" it would result in "node-blog". Note that the machine
 *     name will often be in a short form of the human readable label.
 *   - node-teaser: Nodes in teaser form.
 *   - node-preview: Nodes in preview mode.
 *   The following are controlled through the node publishing options.
 *   - node-promoted: Nodes promoted to the front page.
 *   - node-sticky: Nodes ordered above other non-sticky nodes in teaser listings.
 *   - node-unpublished: Unpublished nodes visible only to administrators.
 * - $title_prefix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
 *   appears in the template.
 * - $title_suffix (array): An array containing additional output populated by
 *   modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
 *   the template.
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $node: Full node object. Contains data that may not be safe.
 * - $type: Node type, i.e. story, page, blog, etc.
 * - $comment_count: Number of comments attached to the node.
 * - $uid: User ID of the node author.
 * - $created: Time the node was published formatted in Unix timestamp.
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 * - $zebra: Outputs either "even" or "odd". Useful for zebra striping in
 *   teaser listings.
 * - $id: Position of the node. Increments each time it's output.
 *
 * Node status variables:
 * - $view_mode: View mode, e.g. 'full', 'teaser'...
 * - $teaser: Flag for the teaser state (shortcut for $view_mode == 'teaser').
 * - $page: Flag for the full page state.
 * - $promote: Flag for front page promotion state.
 * - $sticky: Flags for sticky post setting.
 * - $status: Flag for published status.
 * - $comment: State of comment settings for the node.
 * - $readmore: Flags true if the teaser content of the node cannot hold the
 *   main body content.
 * - $is_front: Flags true when presented in the front page.
 * - $logged_in: Flags true when the current user is a logged-in member.
 * - $is_admin: Flags true when the current user is an administrator.
 *
 * Field variables: for each field instance attached to the node a corresponding
 * variable is defined, e.g. $node->body becomes $body. When needing to access
 * a field's raw values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these
 * variables. Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired field
 * language, e.g. $node->body['en'], thus overriding any language negotiation
 * rule that was previously applied.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_node()
 * @see template_process()
 */
?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <article id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (!$page): ?>
      <header>
    <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if (!$page): ?>
      <h2 class="title" <?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

      <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
        <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted; ?></span>
      <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (!$page): ?>
      </header>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // Hide comments, tags, and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <?php if (!empty($content['links'])): ?>
    <footer>
      <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
    </footer>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  </article> <!-- /.node -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, @No Sssweat I tried and renamed my file node--code-excerpt.tpl.php (and clear the cache) but now I get a lot of errors, not only on the page itself but even on the Home » Administration » Configuration » Development page in drupal

`code`    Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in include() (line 8 of C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.41\sites\all\themes\theme_test\node--code_excerpt.tpl.php).`code`
Can't paste the whole thing as it is too long

Comment: @jazzo what did you put inside the file?

Comment: for now, I literally copied what was inside page.tpl.php (so html + php tags) and I added a `var_dump($directory);`, nothing else

Comment: also you need to put inside your theme's templates folder `sites/all/themes/custom_theme/templates`

Comment: ah OK, it's not inside a template folder, it's directly inside `sites/all/themes/custom_theme`, let me try that

Comment: Additionaly you should use the content of node.tpl.php as default content for your custom template.

Comment: OK done, now the template is inside a template folder and cleared the cache. I still get those errors but now only when I go into edit mode for the page that uses that template and the page itself has missing fields, as if something is broken. Here are all the errors: [link](http://pastebin.com/59dxagef)

Comment: My template folder doesn't have any `node.tpl.php`, where can I get it from? any other theme like bartik?

Comment: @jazzo yes, try using bartiks node.tpl.php

Comment: still not good and getting the errors. SO to summarize: I have the template folder now and inside I have: `node.tpl.php` from bartik as it is, `page.tpl.php` and `node--code_excerpt.tpl.php`. The good thing is that the page in question is using the `node--code_excerpt.tpl.php` file, but maybe there is something wrong with the file itself. Here it is, content of node--code_excerpt.tpl.php pasted:[link](http://pastebin.com/16CVU0DR)

Comment: @jazzo try mine, updated my answer.

Comment: @NoSssweat, thanks just tried, no joy. Also might be worth noting that the errors were there even before I copied the node file into the template folder. Something seems to be going on with my `node--code_excerpt.tpl.php` I wonder if there is something that needs to be an array but it isn't. Also, might be worth mentioning that, as far as I know, I'm not using any preprocess function anywhere

Comment: darn...now I can't clear the cache anymore, as I get another error:`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'drupal_test.cache_filter' n'existe pas: TRUNCATE {cache_filter} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 168 of C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.41\includes\cache.inc).`

Comment: copy my `node.tpl.php` file to your `node--code_excerpt.tpl.php`

Comment: OK that worked, the errors I had before are now gone, the new page is using the `node-code_excerpt.tpl.php` correctly, but unfortunately something else must have gone wrong in the process as now that cache error still persists. Do you reckon I should reinstall drupal again or open another thread for that?

Comment: @jazzo up to you.

Comment: eh eh, will google around and see if I can resolve it, if not it's a new installation I am afraid. Do you know what was wrong with the old `node-code_excerpts.tpl.php`? I mean do you have an idea why it was throwing all those errors? Also, I suppose the `node.tpl.php` is now redundant since we copied its content into `node-code_excerpts.tpl.php`

Comment: @jazzo I have no idea why the old node--code-excerpt.tpl.php was throwing those errors.